# How can I find the runlevel of the processes of /etc/init.d?

Tags: find, runlevel

I want to find out in which runlevel the files of `/etc/init.d‍` are started. Has someone any idea? I thought there might be the option to find it with the `find` command

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Run:

```
cd /etc/init.d
grep Default-Start *
```

Results:

```
dbus:# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
docker:# Default-Start:      2 3 4 5
gdomap:# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
...
```

Just to note, from `man runlevel`:

```
   ┌─────────┬───────────────────┐
   │Runlevel │ Target            │
   ├─────────┼───────────────────┤
   │0        │ poweroff.target   │
   ├─────────┼───────────────────┤
   │1        │ rescue.target     │
   ├─────────┼───────────────────┤
   │2, 3, 4  │ multi-user.target │
   ├─────────┼───────────────────┤
   │5        │ graphical.target  │
   ├─────────┼───────────────────┤
   │6        │ reboot.target     │
   └─────────┴───────────────────┘
```

Comment: to add to this answer; check `/etc/rc*.d/` to which which program runs at '*' run level. like for dbus you will find entries in `/etc/rc2.d/` `/etc/rc3.d/` `/etc/rc4.d/` `/etc/rc5.d/`

Comment: Thank you, great help. Can you also tell me what the "S" means, that appears after Default-Start?

Comment: @changepicture it should be single mode: First paragraph of [RunLevel](https://wiki.debian.org/RunLevel)